# Promoting build does not run other projects

Tags: jenkins, cloudbees

I am looking for a way to build continous delivery with cloudbees,so each time a commit is made my code is compiled,unit tested and deployed to staging (running on run@cloud).

For simplity let's call it "staging-build". Then after some manual testing on staging env i would like to have an option to promote a particular (not the last) "staging-build" so the artifact the promoted build produced should be deployed to production env via "prod-build" job.

The basic idea was to configure "promote build" for "staging-build" job with building "prod-build" as promote action. Nevertheless clicking on promote-build does not trigger starting "prod-build". I also tried from the other side: removed building "prod-build" as promote action and enabling "Build when another project is promoted" within "prod-build" configuration. Still no success. After googling for a while i found 
http://blog.cloudbees.com/2012/10/continuous-integration-for-mobile-apps.html. Nevertheless blog entry along with jenkins configuration screenshots do not reflect configurations on https://partnerdemo.ci.cloudbees.com

Answer (score 3):

I finally found the root of problem: jobs to be run on promotion must be prefixed with folder name (obviously in case they are in folder). In other case their run is silently skipped - even promotion log has no "scheduling build for ..." entry. IMHO Jenkins web console should show some kind of warning in that case, just like it does when invalid job name is typed-in.

Answer (score 2):

configuring a promotion to trigger your prod-build job is the way to go. There may be some configuration issue that isn't visible in your question. Please give me your account ID so I can double check your configuration

Comment: account name is assetwell. For the sake of the check i created 2 extra free style jobs: staging and production (on top level). Surprisingly everything works as expected: production" is fired on promoting "staging". My non-working case is job "staging" in folder "pso"